# `Import from illegal package` error

Tags: java, scala, sbt, opencsv

Anyone knows why 
I get the error `Table.scala:8:0: Import from illegal package` from the following code?

Line 8 is referring to `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

```
import org.allenai.common.Logging
import scala.collection.parallel.mutable

import java.io.FileReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

/** Created by i-danielk on 6/11/15.
  */
class Table(fileName: String) extends Logging {
  val (titleRow, contentMatrix) = readCSV(fileName)

  // reading from csv: for future
  def readCSV(file: String): (Array[String], Array[Array[String]]) = {
    val reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))

    val fullContents = for {
      row <- reader.readAll
    } yield {
      row
    }
    (fullContents.head, fullContents.tail.toArray)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using someone's Scalastyle configuration (or some other linter)? Lots of people (rightfully) discourage use of `JavaConversions` in favor of `JavaConverters` (in Scala, at least—`JavaConversions` is more usable from Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: the Scala compiler will never (as far as I know) complain about an import from "an illegal package", so this must be a rule that someone has configured in a linter that the project is using (most likely [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/)).

Many people prefer the more explicit `JavaConverters` (with its `asScala` and `asJava` enrichment methods) to the magical implicit conversions of `JavaConversions`, so the solution is probably just to switch to that package.

Comment: Just a note: JavaConversions  got deprecated in Scala 2.12 and JavaConverters got deprecated in Scala 2.13. CollectionConverters is the new black..